# How to Scroll into selected item in listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am really confused with wp8 listbox scrolling. with below simple code I am scrolling to the selected index (item), but it doesn't work.

```
lsbReadingChapter.SelectionChanged -= lsbReadingChapter_SelectionChanged;
            _lastAyaSelectedIndex = startingAya;
            lsbReadingChapter.ItemsSource = null;
            lsbReadingChapter.ItemsSource = ds.getArabicTextWithTranslation(currentChapter);
            lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex = startingAya;
            lsbReadingChapter.UpdateLayout();
            lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView(lsbReadingChapter.SelectedItem);
            lsbReadingChapter.SelectionChanged += lsbReadingChapter_SelectionChanged;
```

the selectedIndex is always greater than zero, but the listbox show the 1st item in the list and doesn't scroll.

Here is my xaml

```
ListBox x:Name="lsbReadingChapter" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Width="480" SelectionChanged="lsbReadingChapter_SelectionChanged" Loaded="lsbReadingChapter_Loaded">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="480" Orientation="Vertical" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AlternateRowConverter}}" >
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Padding="20,0,30,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HAlignment}" FontSize="{Binding ArabicFontSize}">
                            <Run Text="{Binding Aya}"/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding AyaID, StringFormat=﴿\{0\}﴾}" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="30"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Padding="20,0,30,0" Text="{Binding AyaTranslation}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="{Binding TranslationFontSize}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HAlignment}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I don't know why it doesn't scroll to the selected index?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

finally solved, by calling lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView in grid load parent of Lisbox.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ScrollIntoView` function either by `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` property.

```
lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView(lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex);
```

or

```
lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView(lsbReadingChapter.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void ScrollToSelectedItem(ListBox control)
{
    if (control.SelectedIndex != -1)
        control.TopIndex = control.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView(lsbReadingChapter.Items[lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex]);
```

Comment: I debug that, the selected index is changed, but scroll is not working.